# What the meaning of "lot" here?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

I’d like to ask on the sentence from The Noble Bachelor by Conan Doyle.

> A gentleman entered, with a pleasant, cultured face, high-nosed and
> pale, with something perhaps of petulance about the mouth, and with
> the steady, ***well-opened eye of a man whose pleasant lot it had ever
> been to command and to be obeyed***.

I’m not sure what the latter part of the sentence above means, especially what this “lot” means (and what “it” indicates for that matter).
Does this “lot” mean “destiny, situation” here? Dictionaries say “lot” can signify “people, folks”, so is it used to mean that way, implying his servants or something? I don’t know.
And can someone tell me which word this “it” in the latter part of the sentence indicates? I thought this “it” refers to “eye” here. Is so, what does that make the overall sentence means? I’m not really sure.
Could someone clear it up for me please? Thanks.

Comment: 'pleasant lot' = 'good fortune' or 'blessed destiny'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have missed this meaning in the many definitions of *lot*:

> 3. b: "one's way of life or worldly fate : one's fortune*"
>
>    //"the lot of man, to suffer and to die" — Alexander Pope
>
>    [[Merriam Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lot)

This is the way it is used in your quotation. The gentleman had led a life in which he was accustomed to command and to be obeyed. His fortune or way of life (his lot) was to be in charge of others.

*whose pleasant lot it had ever been to command and to be obeyed* = *whose pleasant lot had always been to command and to be obeyed*. The use of "it", referring to and emphasizing the immediately preceding noun is optional. If used it gives a more literate feeling to the sentence.

> "it has ever been my wont to give my love without thought of obligation." - [Timon of Athens - Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/timonofathensedi00shakuoft/timonofathensedi00shakuoft_djvu.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *lot* means *destiny* here (one's 'lot in life').

> [He looked like] a man who had always been in the pleasant situation of being able to command and be obeyed.